# Sharepoint Application 2013 custom list new page

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have a sharepoint-hosted application and some lists within this app. I want to replace default new form with my own page. I've modified schema.xml for the list:

```
    <Forms>
      <Form Type="DisplayForm" Url="DispForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
      <Form Type="EditForm" Url="EditForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
      <Form Type="NewForm" Url="NewForm.aspx" SetupPath="features\$SharePoint.Feature.DeploymentPath$\Pages\Default.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
    </Forms>
```

But there is an error during deployment "Cannot find the file specified". How can I point to my page in sharepoint-hosted application list schema.xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the form within the same folder as the List:

```
    <Form Type="NewForm" Url="NewForm.aspx" Path="CustomNewForm.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" UseLegacyForm="FALSE" />
```

or if you have your custom form within a Pages folder:

```
    <Form Type="NewForm" Url="NewForm.aspx" Path="~site/Pages/CustomNewForm.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" UseLegacyForm="FALSE" />
```

**IMPORTANT:** 
Don't forget to right-click the custom form and select **Properties**,
 
then set **Deployment Type: ElementFile**

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, I think you should change your backslashes in each of the setup paths to forward slashes, as they refer to specific places within the SharePoint application on IIS.